# How to start Firefox with given arguments in JSON string?

Tags: json, windows, firefox, visual-studio-code

### Background

---

I use the Live Server extension for VS Code and I'm trying to make it open Firefox with a specific profile.

### Problem

---

I either don't know how to specify command line arguments in JSON format, or it's not possible.

Currently, my `settings.json` contains this line.

```
"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "'C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Nightly\\firefox.exe' -P webdev"
```

This results in the following error.

[image: windows error message - cannot find path]

### What I have tried so far

---

I did a sanity check by running the same command from command line directly. It turns out I can't have arguments inside strings.

This **does not** work in cmd:

```
C:\Users>"C:\Program Files\Firefox Nightly\firefox.exe -P webdev"
```

It results in the same error I have seen before.

> '"C:\Program Files\Firefox Nightly\firefox.exe -P webdev"' is not
> recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
> batch file.

This however works very well:

```
C:\Users>"C:\Program Files\Firefox Nightly\firefox.exe" -P webdev
```

To pass on the arguments `-P webdev` I have to either be in the directory where `firefox.exe` is and run it by calling its name, or put the arguments after the ending quote.

**All the ways I have tried specifying this in JSON that don't work:**

```
"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Nightly\\firefox.exe -P webdev"

"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Nightly\\firefox.exe /P webdev"

"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "\"%ProgramFiles%\\Firefox Nightly\\firefox.exe\" -P webdev"

"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "\"C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Nightly\\firefox.exe\" -P webdev"

"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "'%ProgramFiles%\\Firefox Nightly\\firefox.exe' -P webdev"

"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "'C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Nightly\\firefox.exe' -P webdev"
```

**Examples that do work:**

```
"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Nightly\\firefox.exe"
```

This one is plain and simple and has no arguments.

```
"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Nightly\\firefox.exe --private-window"
```

This exemple is given in the extension documentation. I'm not sure why this one even works? If arguments must be put outside of quotes, then this should not work. But this is a single argument whereas `-P webdev` consists of two arguments (separated by a space).

Comment: A JSON string can encode *any* sequence of characters. If you need a specific argument, specify that argument. It's unclear what sort of magic you assume to be in place. There isn't any.

Comment: Yes, but what sequence of characters is equivalent to `"C:\Program Files\Firefox Nightly\firefox.exe" -P webdev` as used from the cmd command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape inner quotes, but you can't escape outer quotes which are required for a JSON string to be a valid JSON string.

So if you're modifying a configuration file in JSON format and you need to specify the absolute path to a program that requires you to wrap it in inner set of quotes in order to pass on arguments to the program, then you will have to look for an alternative solution.

This line in CMD...

```
"C:\Program Files\Firefox Nightly\firefox.exe" -P webdev
```

Should be encoded like this in a JSON configuration file to get the same result (starting firefox.exe with profile named webdev)...

```
""C:\Program Files\Firefox Nightly\firefox.exe" -P webdev"
```

But this is invalid JSON string so this will not work (or it will have unexpected behavior, like being automatically overridden by other settings).

And you can't escape the outer set of quotes, because you're expected to wrap everything in quotes...

```
\""C:\Program Files\Firefox Nightly\firefox.exe" -P webdev\"
```

So this is also invalid.

So you need to come up with a different way to point to the program without using quotes and pass on arguments to it, before you then consume it in a JSON string.

One way to do it is to use a batch file (`C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test.bat`) with the following line.

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Firefox Nightly\firefox.exe" -P webdev %*
```

Then you point your JSON at this instead.

```
"liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\test.bat"
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to specify this in JSON directly. Someone can correct me if I'm wrong. I will explore other approaches. In the meantime, this will have to do for now.